# Creating a table using mysql python with variable values

Tags: mysql, flask, mysql-python

I'm trying to create a table in MySQL using python-flask. The table name is the 'id' parameter, which I pull from my server. I want this id to be the name of the table that I'm creating, but when I try to do so, I get the following error:

**'mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '46490210 (user varchar(50), message varchar(150))' at line 1'**

Here's the python-sql code for reference.

```
#the file name is chat_db.py

def createTable(id):
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (user varchar(50), message varchar(150))",(id,))
    db.commit()
```

Here's the Flask code (without the decorators):

```
import chat_db as roomdb 
import random

def rand_id():
    return random.randint(10000000,99999999)

def roomTable():
    roomdb.createTable(rand_id())

roomTable()
```

Please help out! :)

Comment: that is not allowed in mysql. You have to put a letter before tehnumber or such

Comment: @nbk That did not rectify my problem. I made the following change in 
 the 'roomTable' function: 

`roomdb.createTable('a'+str(rand_id()))` (added 'a' to the beginning of the id) 

Yet I still receive the following error: "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''a93937637' (user varchar(50), message varchar(150))' at line 1".

Comment: @nbk If I misinterpreted your solution, please provide a solution with reference to the code I used in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onlym Number aren't alowwed in mysql, so you need a Letter before the number
In my example i used the Letter `A`, but it can  be of course any Text you like.

But i don't see why you want to do such a thing in a loop.

```
def createTable(id):
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS A%s (user varchar(50), message varchar(150))",(id,))
    cnx.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked out. However, I'm curious to know why this modification to my original code didn't work out: 
`roomdb.createTable('a'+str(rand_id())) `

Comment: your code adds '(single quote) to the text which mysql doesn't like, when you have a number it doesn't